# Programatically added UIScrollview is not Scrolling

Tags: ios, scrollview

i've been searching for a solution from 3 days and i haven't got a right one.
I added 26 buttons for 5s screen(programatically)and also the scrollview,but after running what found was the scrollview is not at all scrolling neither on 5s nor 4s.

Comment: It would save a lot of copy and pasting to put some of your code in a loop.

Comment: Waow, first make sure that code is displayed as code when submitted. Then, your problem is not linked to the number of button you add, so reduce it by just ading one button that require scroll to be displayed (in other words, reduce the problem to highlight the issue)

Comment: "I added 26 buttons for 5s screen(programatically)" what about collection View? Add 26 buttons on scrollView it is not good, and i see a lot of copy-paste in your code ))

Comment: sorry for your inconvenience,actually I'm new to Iphone app development,

Comment: thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your concern,finally i got the solution that i was looking for,the mistake i did was i added a scrollview to the view and later added buttons to the scrollview which resulted a malfunction,instead i added a second view to the scrollview and added buttons to the second view and finally it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,menu1.frame.origin.y+menu1.frame.size.height);
```

menu1 is your last subview on scroll

Answer (score 0):

For 4s device:

```
 scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
 scrollview.setContentSize = CGSizeMake(320,568);
```

I think for 5s you don't need scrollview.I think all the buttons will be displayed in the view.You don't have to scroll it. But if you want to add then you can do that

```
  scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)]; 
  scrollview.setContentSize = CGSizeMake(320,568);
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase your Content size height value to the number of button * height of each button, which makes your scrollview to scroll till the last content you have added

`scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,numberOfButtons*eachbuttonheight);`